# Trim a QLineEdit automatically: possible?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I wanted to limit the input of `QLineEdit`:  no leading space. Is that possible ?

I shouldn't be using, e.g. the `textEdited()` signal, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `editingFinished()` signal for that, it will be triggered when the text input loses focus or the user presses the enter key.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, also consider a validator - you can reject leading spaces from being entered at all, that way.

Comment: May I know how can I reject leading space in validator?  Thanks

Comment: Well you're passed the current string to validate, if it starts with leading space, return QValidator::Invalid. It's quite possible the built-in QRegExpValidator can do this with no subclassing, even easier.